# Flexbox content disappear in UC browser (in Android)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

content is disappear when it wrapped with flex css, it only happen in UC browser for Android, anyone have solution or hacks for this?

Comment: It is very unclear what you ask. Post a code snippet of the part that goes wrong and we might be able to do more than guess

Answer (score 0):

**That's most likely because the browser doesn't fully support it.**

According to [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) you have to use [prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix) for it to work even on the latest version.

However even then it's not 100% supported.

[image]